# How to prevent ajax request from being canceled on iphone?

Tags: javascript, ajax, model-view-controller

I'm using MVC 4, and on submit form I'm getting a pdf file. In this form I'm using ajax get request to get some data from the controller. The problem is that when i get the pdf file after I submit the form, on iphone the pdf is opened inline on the same page, and after i go back to the page of my program the ajax requests on all my pages stop working (they all get canceled before they complete their requests). I've been looking for some solutions, but nothing helped. The solutions I've tried are;
cache: false - in the ajax request.
Adding to the url a time parameter that every time the time parameter will change.
I've been reading about this problem, and the only thing I have found that if the ajax request status is returning 0, it means that the ajax request is getting canceled before it completes.
It's happening only on iphone because it's opening the pdf file inline instead of downloading it like it does on everything else.
Please help me to solve this problem, I've been trying to do so for a long time now.

This is the ajax code I'm using:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/IncomeExpenses/UpdateInvoiceData?time=' + new Date().getTime(),
    data: str,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        //some code
    }
});
```

Comment: i'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but can't you open the pdf after the ajax call is made, this way it doesn't cancel your ajax call?

Comment: I am opening the pdf after the ajax call is made. The first time I open my program on iphone browser (doesn't matter witch) it works, but after I submit the form and get the pdf file, the ajax calls stop working. It works only if I close the browser from being on background.

Answer (score 0):

Making `async: false` would help overcome this issue. By this, We enforce the browser to wait for the response back by making the AJAX request synced with the browser.